# What are some examples for conditions that change their meaning due to operator precedence changes in Postgresql 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

In Postgresql 9.5, one of the changes listed in the release notes as breaking backwards compatibility is this:

> Adjust operator precedence to match the SQL standard (Tom Lane)
>
> The precedence of <=, >= and <> has been reduced to match that of <, >
> and =. The precedence of IS tests (e.g., x IS NULL) has been reduced
> to be just below these six comparison operators. Also, multi-keyword
> operators beginning with NOT now have the precedence of their base
> operator (for example, NOT BETWEEN now has the same precedence as
> BETWEEN) whereas before they had inconsistent precedence, behaving
> like NOT with respect to their left operand but like their base
> operator with respect to their right operand. The new configuration
> parameter operator_precedence_warning can be enabled to warn about
> queries in which these precedence changes result in different parsing
> choices.

I'm finding it difficult to come up with a query that changes its meaning because of the above change. What are some examples for such queries?

[New precedence table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE)

[Old precedence table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select 1>2 is true;`

in 9.4 it would be interpreted as `select 1> (2 is true);`, which is invalid and throws the error `error: argument of IS TRUE must be type boolean, not type integer`

In 9.5 it would be  interpreted as `select (1>2) is true;`, which is valid and return `false`.

These versions are still available on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) to test.

Comment: Can I challenge you with a more real world example? It's unlikely that someone would test `1>2` with `is true` rather than just use the result as is.

Answer (score 1):

A realistic example would be a check constraint that says `approved_by IS NULL = approved_at IS NULL`, which works in 9.4 but fails in 9.5. If the second column is a boolean, it will instead fail silently and produce an incorrect result. E.g. `false is null = true is null` evaluates to `true` in 9.4. but to `false` in 9.5.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i87TdE15yTo4jhaoSh5fi4/1